# Leaflet Editable, cancel drawing

Tags: leaflet

I need to cancel drawing in Leaflet Editable plugin and delete layer from map

```
map.on('editable:drawing:cancel', function (e) {
    map.removeLayer(e.layer);
});

var onKeyDown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {  // esc button
        if (!this.editTools._drawingEditor) return;
        map.editTools._drawingEditor.cancelDrawing();
    }
};
L.DomEvent.addListener(document, 'keydown', onKeyDown, map);
```

I use this, layer deleted, but Leaflet send error

```
NotFoundError: Node was not found
```

And next drawing attempt doing bad, some errors.

What is the correct way?

Comment: Well, i guess some answer is:

`map.editTools._drawingEditor.disable();`

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle?

Comment: replace this line 'map.editTools._drawingEditor.cancelDrawing();' with map.editTools._drawingEditor.disable(); or map.editTools.stopDrawing();

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the stopDrawing method to cancel a drawing in progress.

```
map.editTools.stopDrawing()
```